# How to use the .addField without the second comment in discord.js

Tags: discord.js

So it's pretty simple. I just don't want the second comment of `.addField` eg.

```js
.addField(advice.slip.advice)
```

but it keeps on showing undefined for the second comment...

[image: here is an image for example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide something as a value in a field, otherwise it will be undefined. But for your example you can just make:

```js
.setDescription(`**${advice.slip.advice}**`)
```